# Boost Asio receive unknown Number?

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

I wrote a Http/Rest Client.

The Main Problem is that i recieve some unkown digits within the requested data.
I really don´t know where they come from..

```
e0b
<html>
<head>
[...]
</body>
</html>
0
```

You see the **e0b** and the **0** at the end. 
In big xml files for example i got something like this:

```
<sometag id="somei
2000
d"><child>
...
</child></some
2000
tag>
```

It is irreproducible by me.

My Code:

```
  // read the response status code
  boost::asio::streambuf httpStreamBufferResponse;
  boost::asio::read_until(httpSocket, httpStreamBufferResponse, "\r\n");

  // check status code and validate
  istream httpResponseIStream(&httpStreamBufferResponse);

  // temp var for version
  string sHttpVersion;
  httpResponseIStream >> sHttpVersion;

  // temp var for status code
  unsigned int uiStatusCode;
  httpResponseIStream >> uiStatusCode;

  // fetch status message and switch it
  string sStatusMessage;
  getline(httpResponseIStream, sStatusMessage);
  if(!httpResponseIStream || sHttpVersion.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/"){
    new Note(eNotesType(ERROR), "Request Interrupt", "Invalid Request Response");
    Log::write("ERROR: Request Interrupt: Invalid Request Response");
  }
  // != 200 even means that something is not OK
  if(uiStatusCode != 200){
    this -> sHttpStatusCode = uiStatusCode;
    new Note(eNotesType(WARNING), "Request Response " 
      + boost::lexical_cast<string>(uiStatusCode), httpErrorToString.at(uiStatusCode));
    Log::write("WARNING: Request Response " 
      + boost::lexical_cast<string>(uiStatusCode) + ": " + httpErrorToString.at(uiStatusCode));
  }

  // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
  boost::asio::read_until(httpSocket, httpStreamBufferResponse, "\r\n\r\n");

  // Process the response header
  stringstream responseSStream;
  string responseSHeader;
  while (getline( httpResponseIStream, responseSHeader ) && responseSHeader != "\r" ) {
    responseSStream << responseSHeader;
  }
  // store header in member variable
  this -> sHttpResponseHeader = sHttpVersion + " " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(uiStatusCode) + " " 
    + httpErrorToString.at(uiStatusCode) + "\n" + responseSStream.str();

  // read until EOF and writing data to output as we go.
  ostringstream responseOSStream;
  while(boost::asio::read(httpSocket, httpStreamBufferResponse, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error)){
    responseOSStream << &httpStreamBufferResponse;
  }

  // store content in member variable
  this -> sHttpResponseContent = responseOSStream.str();

  // if there is no EOF
  if(error != boost::asio::error::eof){ 
    new Note(eNotesType(ERROR), "Request Interrupt", "Invalid Response End");
    Log::write("ERROR: Request Interrupt: Invalid  Response End");    
  }

// catch not known exceptions properly
} catch (exception& e){
  string exceptionMessage = e.what();
  new Note(eNotesType(ERROR), "Exception", exceptionMessage);
  Log::write("ERROR: Exception: " + exceptionMessage);    
}

// log http standby
Log::write("http status: standby");
```

It would be a great pleasure if anybody got **ANY** idea where this come from..?!

My nerves are on edge..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is claiming HTTP/1.1 compliance and doesn't actually comply with HTTP/1.1's requirements. Either don't claim HTTP/1.1 compliance or make sure your code does everything the standard says a client must do.

> All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the "chunked" transfer-coding, and MUST ignore chunk-extension extensions they do not understand. -- [HTTP/1.1 specification, section 3.6.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1)

Comment: how did you see that it´s claiming HTTP/1.1 ? you made my day with this simple statement..

Comment: You wouldn't get chunked encoding unless you either claimed HTTP/1.1 or the server was broken. The former seemed more likely. (Plus, when you've seen the same issue 832 times, you have a pretty good idea what usually causes it.)